# Readline: Binding an ANSI escape sequence to a key

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, readline

I would like to bind a key with bash / readline, to clear the bottom of my console screen.

The ANSI sequence to clear the bottom of the screen is `\e[J`, so I tried to add the following line to my `.inputrc`, but it doesn't work, it simply ignores the three chars:

```
Control-N: "\e[J"
```

If I add some test chars inside the string:

```
Control-N: "BEFORE \e[J AFTER"
```

, then the string `BEFORE` is inserted and it stops there.

For the moment, I found this workaround, but it obviously displays a line with the `echo` command, and I don't want it:

```
Control-N: "echo -ne \"\\e[J\"\n"
```

Is it possible to send ANSI sequences with a `readline` binding?

Comment: As Thomas Dickey remarks, how does what you want differ from pressing Ctrl+L or binding Ctrl+N to `clear-screen`?

Comment: I know about `clear-screen`, but I like to keep an eye on what was written above, and `clear-screen` clears everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two parts:

- bash lets you bind a key to the readline [clear-screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-Moving.html#index-clear_002dscreen-_0028C_002dl_0029) function (which seems to be the original goal).
- in bash, readline's purpose is to prepare text (by editing, etc) for issuing commands to *bash*.  An escape sequence would be sent to the *terminal*.  None of the [listed functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Function-Index.html#Function-Index) for readline would act as a replacement for `echo` or `printf`.

Key bindings for readline expect a single function-name or literal string.  In your example, readline read what it considered a possible function name, and ignored the rest of the line.

So: no, bash/readline provide no useful features for echoing an escape sequence directly as a key-binding.  You have to go another level, as noted, using `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

By improving a bit the use of the `echo` command inside `.inputrc` command, if finally got the result I wanted exactly:

I put the following func in my `.bashrc`, choosing deliberately a short name for the func:

```
cbs()
{
    echo -ne '\e[J\e[F\e[2K'
    history -d $(history 1)
}
```

It uses ANSI sequences to clear the bottom of the screen (`\\e[J`), then move the cursor back to the same line it was originally (`\\e[F`) before finally clearing the line where the command was inserted (`\\e[2K`).

The command is also directly removed from the bash history to not polluate it.

A short name for the command is important, because if the line wraps inside a too small console window, the trick won't work correctly.

Then I bind <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> accordingly in `.inputrc`:

```
Control-N: "cbs\n"
```